# Vector drawable for ImageView with dp-sized lines

Tags: android, android-layout

Let's assume an `ImageView` that should have scalable drawable inside.

Let's say I want draw a cross using two lines with **strokeWidth = 1dp**, no matter what is the real size of the ImageView.

I found `VectorDrawable` but I cannot use **dp** unit there. I also need to generate this content dynamically.

Does anyone have an idea how to achieve this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I made a custom view, see especially page about [Custom Drawing](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html). It fits best my needs.